# iOS 7 Tips and Tricks?

Tags: discussion

Suitability of Question:

As iOS 7 is new. Is it suitable to ask a question regarding:

**iOS 7 Tips and Tricks ?**

Similar questions include:

[Got any tips or tricks for Terminal in Mac OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5435/got-any-tips-or-tricks-for-terminal-in-mac-os-x)

[Please share your hidden OS X features or tips and tricks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400/please-share-your-hidden-os-x-features-or-tips-and-tricks)

Is this wiki style question now not so desirable anymore ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have one here:

[What features in iOS 7 make a difference?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101382/what-are-some-hidden-or-undocumented-features-in-ios-7)

Free free to just tag on the coat-tails of it without starting a new one.

Comment: Ok fine. Its already been started :)